# RACCommand initializer signal doesn't hit executingSignals

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I've been working on an [MVVM example](https://github.com/eliperkins/MVVMExample), using ReactiveCocoa that is a simple collection of App.net posts in a collection view which loads more posts before hitting the edge of the collection view.

I'm having an issue, however, with a command on my view model. I've created a command that loads posts via an AFNetworking client, and responds back after they've been modeled. When it completes, it sends the response to the signal that the command that was created with, and completes the signal.

```
self.loadPostsCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [[EPHTTPClient sharedClient] getGlobalTimelinePostsWithSuccess:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            [self.posts addObjectsFromArray:responseObject];
            [subscriber sendNext:responseObject];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
        }];

        return nil;
    }];
}];
```

In my view, I create a signal to send the remaining post count over as such.

```
@weakify(self);

RACSignal *postsRemainingSignal = [[RACObserve(self.collectionView, contentOffset) map:^(id value) {
    // The value returned from the signal will be an NSValue
    CGPoint offset = [value CGPointValue];
    NSNumber *postsPassed = @(floorf(offset.x/320) + 1);

    return @([self.postQueue.posts count] - [postsPassed integerValue]);
}] distinctUntilChanged];
```

I send these values to a subject on my view model.

```
// Send the values of the posts to the view model
[postsRemainingSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [self.postQueue.postsRemainingSubject sendNext:x];
}];

// When the load command is executed, update our view accordingly
[self.postQueue.loadPostsCommand.executionSignals subscribeNext:^(RACSignal *loadSignal) {
    [loadSignal subscribeCompleted:^{
        @strongify(self);
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}];
```

The subject in the view model is instantiated as such:

```
// Create a subject to send view values to
self.postsRemainingSubject = [RACSubject subject];

// Load more posts when less than 4 posts remain
[self.postsRemainingSubject subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    if ([x integerValue] < 4) {
        [self.loadPostsCommand execute:nil];
    }
}];
```

**Everything works as expected, except for sending values and completion to my command's signal. The network request happens, my posts are modeled, however, the view never receives any values on the `self.postQueue.loadPostsCommand.executionSignals` signal.**

Again, [my project is on GitHub](https://github.com/eliperkins/MVVMExample/tree/reload-signal-rework) in the branch reload-signal-rework. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you update your repo? I tried to dig into this but the repo has code different from what's in this question.

Comment: Check the branch reload-signal-rework here: https://github.com/eliperkins/MVVMExample/tree/reload-signal-rework

Comment: I cannot read, please accept apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're subscribing to `executionSignals` after sending to `postsRemainingSubject` (which is what ultimately causes the `-execute:` to be called).

If you move your subscription to `executionSignals` above the block that sends on `postsRemainingSubject`, then you'll see subscription block get called.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Is this the proper use case for a subject here? I notice RACs docs say to shy away from subjects...

Comment: Instead of using a subject in that case, you could use a conventional property. Replace `-sendNext:` with assignment to the property, and replace any subscribers to the subject with subscribers to `RACObserve(obj, property)`. Does that make sense?